# Control+J equivalent using Text to Columns functionality

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function

I'm trying to split a cell with multiple rows of data into into individual cells. Using the Text to Columns functionality.

Text: https://www.howtoexcel.org/tips-and-tricks/how-to-separate-data-in-a-cell-based-on-line-breaks/

Video: https://trumpexcel.com/split-multiple-lines/

I found this video where he uses the Text to Columns functionality but in the video at the bottom of the page it shows him entering "control+j" for the other character. However, on macOS It doesn't work. What is the equivalent of this on the macOS?

thanks.

Comment: I guess the used link comprises solution for Window based Excel.. better search for MAC based Excel !!

Comment: Try enter ^l and paste to Other optionl.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, from testing this and from reading elsewhere, it's a 2-step process on the Mac.

1. Convert the newlines to something else, I recommend am unusual character like a tilde or pipe.  The link below recommends a comma, but that won't work if you're doing "Last, First" names or "City, State" items.
2. Then use the Text-to-Columns function.

See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_mac2011/mac-excel-2011-text-to-column-carriage-return-as/6cbde588-05b9-4c8d-95ea-1a83476e3a09 for details on #1.